# Why is my script only working in customise mode?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I had this working but I now have a peculiar problem.

In Wordpress have a div with the class `.event-post-content` which displays events using a shortcode. When there are no events I want to display a message.

The code I'm using is as follows...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

if (jQuery('.event-post-content').is(':empty')){
  jQuery('.event-post-content').html('<p style="font-size: 16px;font-family: Source Sans Pro;font-weight:bold;">Sorry, there are no events scheduled in this category at present.</p>');
}
    
});
```

If I look at this on the frontend of the website the message isn't displayed but if I go into 'Customise' mode the message displays?? Any ideas?

Comment: Any messages in the console on the front end? Is the code being run on the front end?

Comment: Ah OK 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined' . I though Wordpress included jQuery?

Comment: I just added link to hosted jQuery in header...working again. Thanks for pointing it out.